# Let $X$ be the random variable having probability density...

Tags: probability, statistics

Let $X$ be the random variable having probability density

$f(x) =
\begin{cases}
c|x-1|,  & 0 < x < 2 \\
0, & \text{otherwise}
\end{cases}$

How to find $F (x) = P (X\le x)$?

Comment: You need to integrate over the whole support and then find $c$ and then integrate over part of the support

Comment: @Henry I already found $c$. It's $=1$

Comment: So now find $F(x)=\int\limits_{y=-\infty}^x f(y) \, dy$ when $x \lt 0$, $0 \lt x \lt 1$, $1 \lt x \lt 2$, or $2 \lt x$

Comment: @Henry I don't understand very well. For example, when x<0, what am I supposed to calculate?

Comment: When $x<0$, $f(x)=0$, so necessarily the integral is zero.

Comment: Ever heard of a cumulative density?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Now that you have found $c = 1,$ you should plot $f(x).$

In R,

```
curve (abs(1-x), 0, 2, ylab = "Density")
  abline(h=0, col="green2");  abline(v=0:2, col="green2")
```

[image]

Notice that for $x \in (0,1),$ we have $f_X(x) = |x - 1| = 1 - x \ge 0.$
Thus, for $x \in (0,1),$ we have
$$F_X(x) = \int_{-\infty}^0 0\, dt + \int_0^x (1 - t)\, dt = x - x^2/2.$$

[image]

What is $F_x(1)?$ Similarly, find $F_X(x) = 1 - x + x^2/2,$ for $x\in (1,2).$

Finally, write the correct expression for $F_X(x),$ using all four intervals mentioned by @Henry.

Remember that $F_X(x)$ must be a non-decreasing function and that $F_X(-\infty) = 0$ and $F_X(\infty) = 1.$ Also, notice that $F_X(x)$ is "flattest" where $f_X(x)$ is smallest.

Answer (score 0):

$F(x)=0$ for $x\lt 0$

$F(x)=\int_0^x(1-u)du=x-\frac{x^2}{2}$ for $0\le x\le 1$

$F(x)=\frac{1}{2}+\int_1^x(u-1)du=1+\frac{x^2}{2}-x$ for $1\lt x\le 2$

$F(x)=1$ for $x\gt 2$
 .

Comment: Something wrong with the part for $0 \le x \le 1.$

Comment: @BruceET It was a typo - I corrected it.